# Making a 0 to n vector in python

Tags: python, vector, numpy

I am a new python user and I was wondering how I could make a 0 to n vector.
I would like the user to be able to input an integer for n, and receive an output of [0,1,2,3,4,5...,n].

This is what I have done so far...

```
from numpy import matrix

n=int(raw_input("n= "))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
K = matrix(i)
print K
```

But this is what I get as an output:

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5]...[n]
```

Transposing the matrix doesn't help. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `numpy.array` instead of `numpy.matrix`

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. You should be getting a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the built-in function:

```
range(n)
```

(Well, should be n+1 if you want a list to be [0, 1, ... , n])

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use `numpy`, you can make use of `arange`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(10)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: `numpy.linspace` can also be very handy for stuff like this.

Comment: @BiRico worth pointing out `linspace` always results in a float array, unlike `arange` which may be integer depending on arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import array
n = int(raw_input("n= "))
k = array(range(n+1))
print k
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain Python (no NumPy dependency):

```
arr = list(range(10))
print(arr)
```

(Posting because even if old, browsing for similar problem go to this one. The range() solution is not optimal depending of further tasks (e.g: remove an item arr.remove(val))).